# munkre topology section 28 question 3

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be limit point compact.

(a) If $f : X → Y$ is continuous, does it follow that $f (X) $is limit point compact?

(b) If $A$ is a closed subset of $X$, does it follow that$ A$ is limit point compact?

for  a): yes  it true,,as continious image of compact set  is  compacts

for b) yes  it is closed beacuse  limit point belong to the set

Is it correct ???

Comment: thanks  @JohnColtraneisJC

Comment: https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-28-limit-point-compactness/

Comment: "A closed subset of a limit point compact space is limit point compact."

Comment: "The image of a limit point compact set under a continuous function does NOT need to be limit point compact." So I was incorrect, (a) is false and (b) is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is false (answered several times on this site already):

Let $X$ be the space $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ where $\mathbb{N}$ has the (usual) discrete topology and $\{0,1\}$ has the indiscrete topology, and $X$ has the product topology of these. Let $f$ be the projection on the first coordinate. ($X$ is defined in exercise 1 in that section, setting it up for you.)

$X$ is limit point compact, because if $A \subseteq X$ and $(n,i) \in A$, then $(n,i')$ is a limit point of $A$ (where $i' = 1$ if $i=0$ and vice versa), because any neighbourhood of $(n,i')$ contains $\{n\} \times \{0,1\}$ and thus $(n,i) \in A \setminus \{(n,i')\}$.

But $f[X]$ is an infinite discrete space, so not limit point compact, as no subset of a discrete space has a limit point.

(b) is true: if $X$ is limit point compact, and $A$ is closed, then any infinite $B \subseteq A$ has a limit point in $X$ and this limit point is in $A$, as $B' \subseteq A' \subseteq A$.

(c) is false: $S_\Omega$ (the first uncountable ordinal in the order topology) is limit point compact but not closed in $S_\Omega \cup \{S_\Omega\}$, the successor ordinal (which Munkres denotes $\overline{S_\Omega}$, I believe).

(d)((a) - (c) under the extra Hausdorff condition)) (c) remains false as the same example works (both are Hausdorff spaces).
(b) remains true, and (a) becomes true, because ($T_1$ is already enough) then a limit point is the same as an $\omega$-limit point (every neighbourhood contains infinitely many points of the set). Those proofs are not hard and can be found on this site as well.

Comment: Thanks  a  lots  @ Henno  sir  according  to munkre topology  C) If  X is  a subspace of the hausdorff space Z , does  it follow that  that  X is closed in Z???     im  not getting this

Comment: can  u   elaborate more  how  it  not closed in $S_\Omega \cup \{S_\Omega\}$ ?

Comment: @lomber iSee page 131, example 3 where the space is introduced. There he shows $\Omega$ lies in the closure of $S_\Omega$, but there is no sequence from it converging to $\Omega$.

Comment: @lomber example 1 on p178 explains why $S_\Omega$ is limit point compact but not compact, as it is not closed in the Hausdorff space $\overline{S_\Omega}$. He basically gives away (c) there.